What does "Belgian" really mean, in the Fast and Furious series?
Tess walks into the pub and asks people if they've seen someone. A
customer warns her not to look, so they end up fighting. Tess grabs
two beers from the bartender and joins Dominic, who's already there:

Tess: Queenie told me I could find you here.
Belgian?
Dominic: Mr. Nobody said he had a daughter.
Tess: He did?

At first, I thought Tess was probably offering Dominic a "Belgian" beer.
But earlier in the movie, when Dominic mentioned the same word while speaking
to Queenie about conveying a message to Nobody, it made me reconsider:

Dom: Tell him I'm ready to have that Belgian, and he'll know where
to go.

What does "Belgian" really mean?

I don't see how the second usage contradicts your interpretation of Belgian beer. It can just as well imply that when "he's ready to have that Belgian beer", it'll be obvious where he will be having it.

There's actually two things here.
"Belgian" is clearly a code-word between Dom and Mr. Nobody for a specific location (i.e. this bar).
Secondly, they use "Belgian" because the beer being served at that location (from looking at a blurry image) is Stella Artois.


Stella Artois is a pilsner beer, first brewed in 1926 by Brouwerij Artois in Leuven, Belgium. In its original form, the beer is 5.2 per cent ABV, the country's standard for pilsners



And this is a fairly obvious product placement.

Probably, given that the bar is in (IIRC) Naples, I would have expected them to serve an Italian beer.

@Paulie_D well, it's not uncommon to find belgian beers in Naples...

Agreed but there are some fine italian brews.

"but there are some fine italian brews": yes, coffee :D

@Valorum "Make sure those logos are facing the camera".  Maybe it's just me, but I don't think I've ever been served a beer in a glass with the logo on it.  Most bars don't want to go to the trouble of keeping separate sets of glasses for every brand they have on tap...

In the UK it's practically mandatory for beer to be served in a logo'd/branded class. To my knowledge having drunk Stella in several European countries it's standard to come in a branded glass. https://www.garage-bar.co.uk/beer-glasses/brands/

IIRC Stella is marketed as a "premium" beer in some countries.

I've seen many branded glasses in bars, @DarrelHoffman. The brand of beer in the glass isn't always related to the brand on the glass. Maybe that's a US thing...

Many Irish Pubs in Europe serve Guinness in a branded glass. @DarrelHoffman

In Belgium -where I live- you expect the beer to be served in the corresponding branded glass - altough it is not always the case. Yes bars have a lot  of different glasses -as well as many people at home (I think I have around 30 different glasses).

@Valorum - "This answer was sponsored by Anheuser-Busch InBev SA/NV"

With additional support from Diageo and Heineken

To extend @Paulie_D's point, Belgian (people and brewers) insist on the right glass for the right beer, to the point where if you order a beer and its corresponding glass is not available, they will come back to you to mention this, so you have the option of picking something else to drink. Not a joke.

@FreeMan: See above comment. It is known to happen on film sets but would very much be frowned upon in real life.

I'm sorry but this answer is simply wrong ... ????  The actual clear reason is explained by @AmiralPatate

"Belgian" does refer to beer, and it's an in-joke between Dominic Toretto and Mr. Nobody, and a bit of a running gag since Furious 7.
Toretto has been seen drinking Corona beer through the series. When Mr. Nobody is introduced in Furious 7, we're shown he knows everything there is to know about Toretto by offering him a bucket of cold Coronas (because it's the kind of small detail that only someone quite familiar with Toretto would know). Mr. Nobody then also mentions he prefers Belgian trappist beer. This discussion between Belgian beer vs Corona comes back a few times in subsequent movies.
In Fast X, the message to Nobody that Dom is "ready to have that Belgian" means two things. First, we can presume it's a standard signal to meet at a predetermined place. Second, the mention of "Belgian" serve to code that the message comes from Toretto, as they're the only two in on the joke about Belgian beer.
Then, by offering Dom a "Belgian", Tess marks herself as both answering his message, and as someone familiar with that in-joke, and thus as an ally sent by Mr. Nobody, as no one else would offer Dom Belgian beer presumably.

This would appear to be the actual answer, bravo !

Belgian ale is apparently a callback to an earlier film in the same series. According to Business Insider:

After Mr. Nobody gets injured in "Furious 7," he tells Dom he really
needs to try a Belgian beer. Earlier on, Dom passed on Mr. Nobody's
beer of choice, opting for a Corona.
By the end, Dom seems to consider giving a Belgian a shot.
In "Fast X," Mr. Nobody's daughter, Tess, unknowingly offers Dom a
Belgian when they meet in Naples. The drink of choice likely made Dom
think of her father.


Unknowingly? It's obviously deliberate.
